# Grunt Inline CSS and Javascript

Tags: tumblr, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

**Short Version:**

Is there a way, using Grunt, to include minified CSS and JavaScript inline?

To use usemin's formatting as an example, I would like to see something like this:

```
<!-- build:css inline -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/foo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bar.css">
...
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js inline -->
<script src="js/foo.js"></script>
<script src="js/bar.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Turned into this something like this:

```
<style>body { color: red; } /*css is here*/</style>
<script>var foo = 1; bar = 'some javascript code is here'; ...</script>
```

**Long Version:**

So, I'm working on a Tumblr theme. In order to use CSS or JS files in a theme, they have to be uploaded to Tumblr. The only way to upload is a crappy little web form that often crashes. I'm trying to avoid this interface until I'm ready to upload the final code because

1. there's no way to delete uploaded files, and
2. while I'm in the middle of development, these extra steps take too much time

To get this, I've been copying my CSS and JS into `<style>` and `<script>` tags in my file, then copying the whole thing into the Tumblr theme editor. It's faster, so I'm happy with that, but manually copying and pasting CSS and JS into a file seems to go against the spirit of Grunt and the automation it provides.

Ideally, I would be able to run `grunt build` and have it spit out an html file with the CSS and JS inline, then I can just copy that into the Tumblr interface (well, ideally, I would be able to copy that HTML file to Tumblr, but Tumblr doesn't provide FTP or SSH or any useful interface, so I'll settle for this).

It seemed like [`grunt-usemin`](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) could provide the functionality I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to get it working as I described. Maybe it's only made to put everything into a separate file.

I'm open to using any Grunt tool if anyone knows of one that could accomplish this.

Comment: I am not aware of any grunt plugins, that can minify inline JS and CSS. The best you can do is manually grind them through online minification tools and then copy-paste into your Tumblr theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used this one before: https://github.com/motherjones/grunt-html-smoosher. It's very straightforward, just provide an input file and output file; no extra configuration, it just finds the files automatically and inlines them.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  smoosher: {
    dist: {
      files: {
        'dest-index.html': 'source-index.html',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As of some time in February 2014, npm installing grunt-html-smoosher stopped working because it depends on a package that has been removed from the npm registry. (See multiple issues on the repo for the project.) There's a pull request to fix it, but grunt-html-smoosher has not seen any development in a year or so. In the meantime, I've published [grunt-html-smoosher-install-fix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-html-smoosher-install-fix) with the fix. This is a hopefully-temporary workaround until the fix gets merged or someone forks the project or something.

Answer (score 1):

Just providing other references that might be useful:

This [grant-inline](https://github.com/chyingp/grunt-inline) task do inline css and javascripts but you can do it selective using the `_inline` parameter. There is also a similar task [grunt-inline-assests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-assets-inline) that do same thing. Both are good to generate HTML e-mails.

Finally, the purpose of [this one](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-frontend/blob/master/docs/overview.md#a-litte-bit-more-about-sails-linking) is a bit different; it inserts all your css and js as externals based on a tag in your HTML. This can be very useful when developing themes and front-ends where you want to have you js or css contained in many small files to easy maintenance. [Sails-linker](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-frontend/blob/master/docs/overview.md#a-litte-bit-more-about-sails-linking) task can be used to inject all css and js while in development and one of the *inliners* above can be used to generate the final production HTML file with CSS and JS *minified* and *inlined*.